# Passing variable to another Python Script

Tags: python, function, variables, arguments

I am having difficulty passing a variable from one function to another function in another python script. I have read the other answers but they have not really helped on this subject.

This is the first file I want to send the variable to( some code omitted for clarity )

```
# TestGUI.py

from Tkinter import *
import serial
import os

class Testgui:
    def __init__(self, master):

    def writetoBOT(self,instruct):
       ser = serial.Serial(6)
       ser.baudrate = 9600
       ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
       ser.timeout = 1            #non-block read
       ser.writeTimeout = 2     #timeout for writ

       if(ser.isOpen() == False):
           ser.open()
           print ser.portstr       # check which port was really used
           ser.write(instruct)
       else :
           ser.write(instruct)
```

This is the sceond file:

```
# TestGUI_2.py

from TestGUI import Testgui

class Tracker:
    def __init__(self):
       pass
    def drive(self,cords, cords1):
       while( cords >= 320):        
           l='l'
           Testgui.writetoBOT(l)      # This is the problem line
```

TypeError: unbound method writetoBOT() must be called with TestGUI instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: you have 2 files, but you're trying to execute *one* script, right? your description is quite confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`writetoBOT` takes 2 arguments: `self` and `instruct`.
call it with a `Testgui` instance:

```
tgui=Testgui(your_master)
tgui.writetoBOT(l)
```

If you want to call it with `Testgui` class, you still need to pass an instance of `Testgui`:

```
tgui=Testgui(your_master)
Testgui.writetoBOT(tgui, l)
```

Comment: Is the (your_master) the calling class? in this case Tracker()?

Comment: @user3257360 this is the argument you need to pass when constructing Testgui instance. See `def __init__(self, master)`. Isn't you who wrote this code?

Comment: To fix my code, I made another class named writetoSerial().and put the serial write code in that. Then imported the function then called it using: from TestGUI_2 import writetoSerial                                          then called the function: l='l'
                     t = writetoSerial()
                     t.writetoBOT(l)

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can make common space for this two scripts, it acn by database - sqllite

For example,

```
# file1.py
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('messages.db')
cur = con.cursor()
#cur.execute('CREATE TABLE message (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, content TEXT, read INTEGER)')
#con.commit()


for x in range(100000):
    if x in range(1, 500): 
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO message (id, name, content, read) VALUES(NULL, "Guido", "van Rossum", 0)')
        con.commit()

# file2.py 
import sqlite3
import time

con = sqlite3.connect('messages.db')
cur = con.cursor()

def listen():
    messages = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM message WHERE read=0')
    if not messages:
        return False 
    for m in messages: 
        print 'get message ', m
        cur.execute("UPDATE message SET read=1 WHERE id=?", m[0])        
        con.commit()
        print 'update db'
    return True

while True: 
    listen()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared `Testgui` as a class. This is to be understood as a skeleton or wireframe (beware, this is a shortcut, not the reality). You need to first create a "real" object out from this skeleton in order to use it.

```
testgui=Testgui(amaster)
```

It is possible in classes to have methods (bound functions) that apply at class level. These are called static methods or class methods. They have to be decorated in python.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_oriented_programming for more information.